# How to scrape <script text/javascript>

Tags: javascript, python, regex, beautifulsoup

so I am trying to figure out how I can possible scrape a javascript tag using regex which I believe might be the easiest way.

The tag looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var spConfig=newApex.Config({
  "attributes": {
    "199": {
      "id": "199",
      "code": "legend",
      "label": "Weapons",
      "options": [
        {
          "label": "10",
          "priceInGame": "0",          
          "id": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "10.5",
          "priceInGame": "0",          
          "id": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "11",
          "priceInGame": "0",          
          "id": [
            "66659"
          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "11.5",
          "priceInGame": "0",          
          "id": [            
          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "12",
          "priceInGame": "0",          
          "id": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "12.5",
          "priceInGame": "0",          
          "id": [           
          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "13",
          "priceInGame": "0",         
          "id": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "4",
          "priceInGame": "0",          
          "id": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "4.5",
          "priceInGame": "0",          
          "id": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "5",
          "priceInGame": "0",         
          "id": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "5.5",
          "priceInGame": "0",        
          "id": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "6",
          "priceInGame": "0",         
          "id": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "6.5",
          "priceInGame": "0",         
          "id": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "7",
          "priceInGame": "0",         
          "id": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "7.5",
          "priceInGame": "0",         
          "id": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "8",
          "priceInGame": "0",          
          "id": [
            "66672"
          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "8.5",
          "priceInGame": "0",          
          "id": [
            "66673"
          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "9",
          "priceInGame": "0",          
          "id": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "9.5",
          "priceInGame": "0",        
          "id": [
            "66675"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "weaponID": "66733",
  "chooseText": "Apex Legends",
  "Config": {
    "includeCoins": false,
  }
});

</script>
```

and I want to scrape all **Label**

Whaht I tried to do is:

```
        for nosto_sku_tag in bs4.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'}):
            try:
                test = re.findall('var spConfig = (\{.*}?);', nosto_sku_tag.text.strip())
                print(test)
            except:  # noqa
                continue
```

but it only returned an empty value of `[]`

so I am here asking what can I do to be able to scrape the labels?

Comment: Please note that the `type="text/javascript"` is no longer needed (introduced I think with html5), so if you are going to crawl the web it won't be there on every page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the attribute using `attr=value` or `attrs={'attr': 'value'}` syntax.

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments

```py
import json
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    html = '''
<script type="text/javascript">

var spConfig=newApex.Config({
  "attributes": {
    "199": {
      "id": "199",
      "code": "legend",
      "label": "Weapons",
      "options": [
        { "label": "10", "priceInGame": "0", "id": [] },
        { "label": "10.5", "priceInGame": "0", "id": [] },
        { "label": "11", "priceInGame": "0", "id": [ "66659" ] },
        { "label": "7.5", "priceInGame": "0", "id": [] },
        { "label": "8", "priceInGame": "0", "id": ["66672"] }
      ]
    }
  },
  "weaponID": "66733",
  "chooseText": "Apex Legends",
  "taxConfig": {
    "includeCoins": false,
  }
});

</script>    
    '''

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    # this one works too
    # script = soup.find('script', attrs={'type':'text/javascript'})
    script = soup.find('script', type='text/javascript')
    js: str = script.text.replace('\n', '')
    raw_json = re.search('var spConfig=newApex.Config\(({.*})\);', js, flags=re.MULTILINE).group(1)
    data = json.loads(raw_json)
    labels = [opt['label'] for opt in data['attributes']['199']['options']]
    print(labels)
```

output:

```
['10', '10.5', '11', '7.5', '8'] ... some removed for brevity
```

Comment: `json.loads()` would be more appropriate than `ast.literal_eval()` here.

Comment: I agree. But it's more forgiving for syntax errors (extra commas etc) and non-json strings, though.

Comment: `"includeCoins": False,` is a syntax error for example (possibly a typo), so `json.loads` doesnt work here

Comment: Hello! So I am just curious because I am not as knowledge as you but wouldn't it better to just do regex to match `newApex.Config` and grab the json inside the tag and then use the json.loads with it? What is different between doing through regex and the way you did it? @abdusco

Comment: Nothing really, I didn't really try crafting the right pattern so I opted for a quick search and replace, but now I've updated the answer to use a regex. `json.loads` would work fine, if `"includeCoins": False,` weren't in the json, because `False` is an invalid value (it should read `false` instead) and `json.loads` cannot parse it.

Comment: ahhh, yeah it should be false, I think I by accident changed to capital F. My bad! But it is supposed to be a lowercase F.

Comment: Also `var spConfig=newApex.Config\(({.*})\);` wouldnt that cause an issue with json.loads in that case due to it has an extra ")" on the end?`

Comment: That pattern matches anything that looks like a JSON object `{ ... }` inside parentheses in `.Config()` method call, which happens to work in our case. But the issue with `json.loads` is caused by the `False` value. Extra parenthesis is escaped with a backslash `\ `

Comment: @abdusco Right you are actually right. I think I do get it now how it is suppoed to work and I think I am finished here thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for the entire row field in the JSON object, use the following;

```
("label":) "([^"]+)",
```

Then if you want to return the actual value, just use

```
\2
```

to pull back the second group